# How to see whether a specific filetype such as .xml exists in a folder?

Tags: python, linux

I'm using Anaconda and Python version 3.7.4. Using Visual Studio Code as my IDE.

I am trying to figure out how to see if a specific file extension exists within a folder, if so, prompt the user whether to delete files of that type. For example, scan a folder and its subfolders to see whether any xml files exist within in the folder, if the scan finds that there are xml files existing within the folder and its subfolders, prompt the user to delete them (prompt would appear after the scan is complete).

I was able to use the os.path.exists module earlier in my code to see whether a file exists within a folder, defining the path where the file would be as a variable x and then using an if statement to test it. Would I be able to use that same code yet modify it to search for a specific extension within that folder and subfolders? The first line for that code being:

```
x ='/home/user/CI6724_J0874321_John/CI6724_Logs.txt'
```

Comment: Does it have to be Python? `rm -i $(find scripts/ -name \*.xml)`

Comment: Unfortunately so. For the project I’m doing, it is required to be written in Python :/

Comment: For more help, post your current code, and tell us what's wrong with it. What happens when you run it, what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See also [ask].

Comment: Ah there’s nothing wrong with it. No errors, no expectations. Just the question at hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you may want are also in the `os` module.

```
import os
dir = '/some/dir'
xml_files = [file for file in os.listdir(dir) if file.lower().endswith('.xml')]
if xml_files:
    ans = input('delete XML files: %s\n[y/N] ' % ', '.join(xml_files))
    if ans.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
        for file in xml_files:
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir, file))
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much :D. Reading this code makes a lot of sense to me now!